# GCLB : Frontend configuration : Error : Invalid value for field 'namedPorts[0].port

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

We are configuring Load Balancing (Through Google Console) "**Frontend configuration**" with 443 and added SSL certificate.

But when we click on update configuration I'm receiving below error

**Error** : **Invalid value for field 'namedPorts[0].port': '0'. Must be greater than or equal to 1**

Anyone ?? can help on same..!!

Comment: See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45974827/3930782).

Comment: There is an issue on ingress-gce about it [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce/issues/75).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a work around to deal with this issue, we can configuring Load Balancing (**Through GCLOUD Command line**) "**Frontend configuration**" with 443 and added SSL certificate.

**List your SslCertificate resources**

```
gcloud compute ssl-certificates list
```

**Configure your SSL certificate resource**

```
gcloud compute ssl-certificates create [SSL_CERTIFICATE_NAME] \
    --certificate [CRT_FILE_PATH] \
    --private-key [KEY_FILE_PATH]
```

**List your target-https-proxies resources**

```
gcloud compute target-https-proxies list
```

**Update a target HTTPS proxy**

```
gcloud compute target-https-proxies update  [PROXY_NAME] \
--ssl-certificate [SSL_CERTIFICATE_NAME]
```

**Reserve a global static IP address** [Optional Step]

```
gcloud compute addresses create [STAIC_IP_NAME] --global
```

**Configure a global forwarding rule**

```
gcloud compute forwarding-rules create [RULE_NAME] \
--global \
--target-https-proxies [PROXY_NAME] \
--address [STAIC_IP_NAME] \
--port-range 443
```