# GCE LoadBalancer : Invalid value for field 'namedPorts[0].port': '0'. Must be greater than or equal to 1

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

In one of my HTTP(S) LoadBalancer, I wish to change my backend configuration to increase the timeout from 30s to 60s (We have a few 502's that do not have any logs server-side, I wish to check if it comes from the LB)

But, as I validate the change, I got an error saying

> Invalid value for field 'namedPorts[0].port': '0'. Must be greater
>   than or equal to 1

even if i didn't change the namedPort.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45030092/6916552) issue seems to be the same, but the only solution is a workaround that does not work in my case :

Thanks for your help,

Comment: can you paste your YAML file? looks like a syntax error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm sure the OP has resolved this by now, but for anyone else pulling their hair out, this might work for you:

There's a bug of sorts in the GCE Load Balancer UI. If you add an empty frontend IP/Port combo by accident, it will create a named port in the Instance Group called `port0` with a value of `0`. You may not even realize this happened because you won't see the empty frontend mapping in the console.

To fix the problem, edit your instance group and remove `port0` from the list of port name mappings.

[image: Instance Group -> Details -> Port name mapping]

Comment: Yep, that did it for me. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to fix this through the CLI? I can't find "Instance groups" through the UI.

Comment: @RobinWinslow, if you just want to see if this is the problem you're having, you can try running: 

`gcloud compute instance-groups list`.

Then run the following command to see if you have `port0` mapped:

`gcloud compute instance-groups get-named-ports <instance-group-name>`

Comment: @RobinWinslow to find the named ports from the UI, go to `Compute Engine > Instance Groups > (Select a Group) > Details (small text link near the top of the page)`.

Comment: I'm having the same issue but unfortunately this appears to not apply to me :/

Comment: I don't have the `port0` on my ports, but I'm still getting the error, I opened an [issue on ingress-gce](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce/issues/75), hopefully it gets resolved soon.

Answer (score 13):

I faced the same issue and @tmirks 's fix didn't work for me.

After experimenting with GCE for a while, I realised that the issue is with the service.

By default all services are `type: ClusterIP` unless you specified otherwise.

Long story short, if your service isn't exposed as `type: NodePort` than the GCE load balancer won't route the traffic to it.

[From the official Kubernetes project](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/26508#issuecomment-222376962):

> nodeport is a requirement of the GCE Ingress controller (and cloud controllers in general). "On-prem" controllers like the nginx ingress controllers work with clusterip:

Answer (score 0):

After many different attempts I simply deleted the ingress object and recreated it and the problem went away. There must be a bug somewhere that leaves artifacts when ingress in updated.