# What is port 0 used for in Kubernetes services?

Tags: kubernetes

When creating a service I see in the list of internal endpoints an entry the looks like `myservice.sandbox-cluster:0 TCP` along with the ports I explicitly opened.  What is the port 0 entry for?

Comment: Are you using ingress in GCE Load Balancer?

Comment: I think load balancer.

Comment: Just checked we're not using GCE load balancer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using the GCE Load Balancer, `port 0` may be created. `port 0` usually means *"use any random free port"*.

Here is the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce/issues/75). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45738404/gce-loadbalancer-invalid-value-for-field-namedports0-port-0-must-be-gr/45974827#45974827) is more info. Email thread about this is [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kubernetes-users/5a-F38hGePs).

Comment: Accepting this answer, we are not using GCE Load balancer, but it may be adding it in there by default according to my colleague.