# why kubernetes has 2/4 internal endpoints?

Tags: apache-kafka, kubernetes, minikube

[image]

Why sometimes kubernetes has 2 internal endpoints for a service, sometimes 4?
why do the internal endpoints always come in pairs?

Comment: Is that a service of type NodePort?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48814326/what-is-port-0-used-for-in-kubernetes-services

Comment: the service is ClusterIP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is based on my loose understanding of things and an assumption. The assumption is that this seems to be the case when the cluster is deployed to GKE.

Since I don't have Kafka manager installed, I will use the example of Kubernetes service, which has a similar port configuration in the console. This service is of type `ClusterIP`

```
Name         Cluster IP     Internal Endpoints
Kubernetes   10.11.240.1    kubernetes:443 TCP
                            kubernetes:0 TCP
```

The port 0 is added by GKE Ingress to randomly select a port for forwarding, as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48814326/what-is-port-0-used-for-in-kubernetes-services) and also related [discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45738404/gce-loadbalancer-invalid-value-for-field-namedports0-port-0-must-be-gr/45974827#45974827)

In case of NodePort service, it is a different story.

```
Name         Cluster IP     Internal Endpoints
hello-web    10.11.249.126  helloweb:8080 TCP
                            helloweb:30193 TCP
```

This can be also seen in the service description. Since service is already exposed on a nodeport, there is no need to additionally expose on a random port.

```
$kubectl describe service helloweb-backend -n default
Name:           helloweb-backend
Type:           NodePort
IP:             10.11.249.126
Port:           <unset> 8080/TCP
NodePort:       <unset> 30193/TCP
Endpoints:      10.8.3.3:8080
```